# How to track BigQuery usage by user/service account

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a BigQuery account which is accessed by many internal and external users/service accounts. Recently, with the growth of bill, we started researching how to increase the visibility of how much cost is going to each user/service account.

I know there is a way to get this info somewhere through the BigQuery API but I was wondering if there is any other easy way to get this info. Has anybody had a similar problem?

**Restating the question:** how to track how much data each BigQuery user/service account has processed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use BigQuery's audit logs (via Stackdriver) to track access and cost details as described in the docs.

A good tip is to export the logs back to BigQuery for analysis.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/audit-logs

Comment: Thanks Graham! You tip led me to the right place. I end up setting up a 'sink' inside Logs Viewer to capture usage logs and dump it into another BigQuery project.

Comment: Great! Can you please accept my answer in that case ;-)